# Error when defining a function containing Integrate

Tags: functions

```
f[p_, x_] := Piecewise[{{p*Exp[-x], 0 < x}, {(1 - p)*Exp[x], x < 0}}, 0];
auxmu[p_, d_] := x^d Piecewise[{{p*Exp[-x], 0 < x}, {(1 - p)*Exp[x], x < 0}}, 0];
val1 = Integrate[auxmu[p, 1], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

mu[p_, d_] := Integrate[x^d f[p, x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

I get error when defining the last sentence.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You probably need conditions on d:

```
f[p_, x_] := Piecewise[{{p*Exp[-x], 0 < x}, {(1 - p) Exp[x], x < 0}}, 0]; 
Integrate[x^d f[p, x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> d > -1]
```

seems to work fine.